# Python Two Sum - Brute Force Approach

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I'm new to Python and have just started to try out LeetCode to build my chops. On this classic question my code misses a test case.

The problem is as follows:

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
>
> Example:
>
> Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,
>
> Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
>   return [0, 1].

I miss on test case [3,2,4] with the target number of 6, which should return the indices of [1,2], but hit on test case [1,5,7] with the target number of 6 (which of course returns indices [0,1]), so it appears that something is wrong in my while loop, but I'm not quite sure what.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        x = 0
        y = len(nums) - 1
        while x < y:
            if nums[x] + nums[y] == target:
                return (x, y)
            if nums[x] + nums[y] < target:
                x += 1
            else:
                y -= 1
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.array = array       
        return None

test_case = Solution()    
array = [1, 5, 7]
print(test_case.twoSum(array, 6))
```

Output returns null on test case [3,2,4] with target 6, so indices 1 and 2 aren't even being summarized, could I be assigning y wrong?

Comment: Your solution only works correctly for sorted lists.

Comment: Also, be sure that x and y are not equal to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit different approach. We will build a dictionary of values as we need them, which is keyed by the values we are looking for.If we look for a value we track the index of that value when it first appears. As soon as you find the values that satisfy the problem you are done. The time on this is also O(N)

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        look_for = {}
        for n,x in enumerate(nums):
            try:
                return look_for[x], n
            except KeyError:
                look_for.setdefault(target - x,n)

test_case = Solution()
array = [1, 5, 7]
array2 = [3,2,4]
given_nums=[2,7,11,15]
print(test_case.twoSum(array, 6))
print(test_case.twoSum(array2, 6))
print(test_case.twoSum(given_nums,9))
```

output:

```
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(0, 1)
```

Comment: I see, I feel like I should have approached it like this to begin with using enumerate. Simpler and more efficient to boot.

Comment: It is always a learning process, but we don't want to reinvent the wheel when we don't have to :P. Glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

A brute force solution is to double nest a loop over the list where the inner loop only looks at index greater than what the outer loop is currently on.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        for i, a in enumerate(nums, start=0):
            for j, b in enumerate(nums[i+1:], start=0):
                if a+b==target:
                    return [i, j+i+1]

test_case = Solution()
array = [3, 2, 4]
print(test_case.twoSum(array, 6))

array = [1, 5, 7]
print(test_case.twoSum(array, 6))

array = [2, 7, 11, 15]
print(test_case.twoSum(array, 9))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
```

Comment: Your solution is pretty clean. I need help understanding the login happening by adding j+i+1. Why the three instead of just i+1? I am curious

Answer (score 2):

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
            """
            :type nums: List[int]
            :type target: int
            :rtype: List[int]
            """
            ls=[]
            l2=[]
            for i in nums:
                ls.append(target-i)

            for i in range(len(ls)):
                if ls[i] in nums  :
                    if i!= nums.index(ls[i]):
                        l2.append([i,nums.index(ls[i])])            
            return l2[0]


x= Solution()
x.twoSum([-1,-2,-3,-4,-5],-8)
```

output

```
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        subsets = []
        for L in range(0, len(nums)+1):
            for subset in itertools.combinations(nums, L):
                if len(subset)!=0:
                    subsets.append(subset)
        print(subsets) #returns all the posible combinations as tuples, note not permutations!
        #sums all the tuples
        sums = [sum(tup) for tup in subsets]
        indexes = []
        #Checks sum of all the posible combinations
        if target in sums:
            i = sums.index(target)
            matching_combination = subsets[i] #gets the option
            for number in matching_combination:
                indexes.append(nums.index(number))
            return indexes
        else:
            return None


test_case = Solution()    
array = [1,2,3]
print(test_case.twoSum(array, 4))
```

I was trying your example for my own learning. I am happy with what I found. I used the `itertools` to make all the combination of the numbers for me. Then I used list manipulation to sum all the possible combination of numbers in your input array, then I just check in one shot if the target is inside the sum array or not. If not then return None, return the indexes otherwise. Please note that this approach will return all the three indexes as well, if they add up to the target. Sorry it took so long :)

Answer (score 0):

This one is more comprehensive cohesive efficient one even so shorter lines of code.

```
nums = [6, 7, 11, 15, 3, 6, 5, 3,99,5,4,7,2]
target = 27
n = 0

for i in range(len(nums)):
    
    n+=1
    if n == len(nums):
      n == len(nums)
      
    else:
        if nums[i]+nums[n] == target:
          # to find the target position 
          print([nums.index(nums[i]),nums.index(nums[n])])
          # to get the actual numbers to add print([nums[i],nums[n]])
```

Comment: I think this might now work in all the test cases, a=[3,3] t=6, a[9,9] t=18

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python solution. First I will share the **brute force approach** solve this problem using two nested loops.
This gives us the **time complexity of O(N²)**.

```
def twoSum1(numbers, target):
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(numbers)):
            if numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target:
                return [i, j]
```

Later I thought to optimise the solution and I come up with an algorithm which gives a **time complexity of O(N logN)**. I haven't wrote the code but the algorithm is as follow:

1. Start left pointer at `number[0]`.
2. Subtract target with first element `diff = target - numbers[0]`
3. Do a BinarySearch lookup for the value at `diff`.
4. If not found, increment left pointer and repeat step 3 until end of element.
5. If found the element return the index.

Then I applied **two pointer approach** and come up with **time complexity of O(N)**.

```
def twoSum2(numbers, target):
    left_ptr, right_ptr = 0, len(numbers)-1
    while (left_ptr < right_ptr):
        sum = numbers[left_ptr] + numbers[right_ptr]
        if sum < target:
            left_ptr += 1
        elif sum > target:
            right_ptr -= 1
        else:
            return [left_ptr, right_ptr]
```

Input:

```
numbers, target = [2,7,11,15], 9
numbers, target = [2,3,4], 6
numbers, target = list(range(1, 101)), 132
```

Output:

```
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[31, 99]
```